# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction - Communications link failure (Spring-boot/jpa/hibernate/connection pool)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, connection-pooling

We have a `REST` request coming into our application which process's various tasks back and forth to the database.  When the request is finished it is unable to post back to the database to make a final update.

We can see that it takes around 9.5 hours to process the request from start to finish.

**Questions**

- We were wondering why this issue is happening and what the best way to fix it is?
- We looked at modifying the `connection-pool` but were thinking we may need to move to a different `connection-pool` or possibly change how `MySQL` is configured?

If you have any details which may help that would be much appreciated.

Thank you

**Config**

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database
  # connection.
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    username: test
    password: test
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

    # Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
    tomcat:
      testWhileIdle: true
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 60000
      validationQuery: SELECT 1

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        # Use hibernates new generator mappings, this is used for the appium port using a TABLE generator
        id.new_generator_mappings: true
```

**Error**

```
ERROR c.m.m.a.config.RestErrorHandler -  Error occurred: POST:/api/testRuns/61376/execute
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

**Stack Trace**

```
     The last packet successfully received from the server was 33,089,829 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8 milliseconds ago.
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
      at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
      at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.service.TestRunService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e48faff9.completeTestRun(<generated>)
      at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController.runTestRun(HomeController.java:145)
      at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController.runTestRun(HomeController.java:60)
      at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dc33ec77.invoke(<generated>)
      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
      at com.miw.mcb.adbservice.controller.HomeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$591244dd.runTestRun(<generated>)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 33,089,829 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8 milliseconds ago.
      at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
      at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
      at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
      at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
      ... 112 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 33,089,829 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8 milliseconds ago.
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3552)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3452)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3893)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4842)
      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
      at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
      at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
      at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67)
      at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:238)
      at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
      at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
      ... 114 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3004)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462)
      ... 133 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is EndOfFileException in java, happens when your cursor start point is on the end point or when database connection closed because of some unexpected exception.
you can use C3P0 as your DataSource which handles the reconnect and is much better in performance. Here's a quick example of a potential configuration in a Spring xml configuration:

```
<bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{systemProperties.dbhost}" />
    <property name="user" value="#{systemProperties.dbuser}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{systemProperties.dbpass}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="100" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
</bean>
```